# How to make the div element with class messages scrollable? Overflow: auto doesn't show a scroll bar and the div can't be scrolled

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the code below, I have a `div` element with class `messages` which contains many children `div` elements with class `message`. I am trying to make that div scrollable whenever the `message` divs inside of it are too many. The problem is that `overflow: auto;` doesn't show the scroll bar and the div doesn't become scrollable for some reason.

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but the parent of the `messages` div has a height of `100vh` and the `messages` div takes `flex: 1` space.

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.chat {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #36393f;
    height: 100vh;
}
.chat-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}
.selected-room-name {
    padding: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.messages {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.message {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #40444b;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    height: 50px;
}
.message:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.form-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.send-message {
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
    flex: 1;
}
.message-input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: #40444b;
    color: #dcddde;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
        <div class='chat-container'>
            <p class='selected-room-name'>Server</p>
            <div class="messages">
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-container">
                <form class='send-message' >
                    <input class='message-input'  placeholder="Type a message">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css, you needed `overflow: overflow-y;` on `.messages{}`. I also gave you a free `position: sticky;` on the room name :)

```css
    *, *:after, *:before {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .chat {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .chat-container {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .selected-room-name {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0px;
        padding: 20px;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 16px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        max-height:100%;
    }
    .messages {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        flex: 1;
        padding: 20px;
        overflow: overflow-y;
        
    }
    .message {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #40444b;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        color: #e0e0e0;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .message:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .form-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .send-message {
        padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
        flex: 1;
    }
    .message-input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        background-color: #40444b;
        color: #dcddde;
        font-size: 14px;
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="chat">
        <div class='chat-container'>
            <p class='selected-room-name'>Server</p>
            <div class="messages">
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
                <div class='message'></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-container">
                <form class='send-message' >
                    <input class='message-input'  placeholder="Type a message">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```